# R: convert large dataframe to matrix

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following tiny subset of my data frame which im trying to cast to a matrix:

```
my.df <- data.frame(person = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                    week = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2),
                    event = c('visit', 'buy', 'visit', 'visit', 'buy', 'visit'))
> my.df
  person week event
1      A    1 visit
2      A    2   buy
3      B    1 visit
4      B    3 visit
5      B    3   buy
6      C    2 visit
```

I tried to do this using the following command applied on the **COMPLETE** data frame:

```
library(reshap2)
acast(my.df, person ~ week, function(x) {sort(as.character(x))[1]},
      value.var = 'event', fill = 'none')
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in unique.default(x) :
  long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1125
```

I think that this has something to do with my large data set. Can someone tell me how can i overcome such a problem?

Comment: Instead of using `reshape2`, one option might be `dcast` from `data.table` i..e `dcast(setDT(my.df), ...`

Comment: this seems to be working fine for this specific example, but i tried this on a different dataframe (similar structure but the `value.var` is now numeric) and i get the following error:


`Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) :
  values must be type 'character',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'`

Comment: I solved the problem. It was my bad